# How to automate Oracle DB installation (like a 'hands-free' install)?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, installation

I installed the Oracle 11g2 'standard' edition using the following [zip-files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html):

```
linux.x64_11gR2_database_1of2.zip
linux.x64_11gR2_database_2of2.zip
```

I used the [installation guide by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24321/toc.htm) which I found quite tedious, e.g. you need to install/configure an X-Server because the default installer is a GUI which you have to 'babysit' for some time.

Is there a way to automate a default Oracle installation?

I mean something like a script where I can specify: tell me what yum/apt-packages are missing, here are my oracle-zip-install-files, install it under $MY_BASEDIR and for everything else use some sane defaults!

And no GUI.

I know that there is an express-edition which comes as an rpm - this looks convenient on the first glance, but it seems to exclude some stuff the 'standard' edition includes, e.g. Pro*C.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two solutions:

Install Oracle manually the first time. Then zip all `ORACLE_HOME` and for future installation simply:

1. Unzip oracle_home into the new home
2. Run `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/relink all`
3. Run `./runInstaller -silent -attachHome ORACLE_HOME="<Oracle_Home_Location>" ORACLE_HOME_NAME="<Oracle_Home_Name>"`

SID is a property of the database/instance and is separate from installation of the software.

---

Other solution (not my preferred but probably the preferred for mass deployment) is to create a response file. The sample is available in the installation dir:

```
<11g Disk>/database/response/enterprise.rsp
```

Copy this file, edit it and replace default values with your ones (mainly the path, install type, etc). Then run:

```
./runInstaller -silent -responseFile myresponsefile.rsp
```

You can also install the DB manually the first time and record the response file witht he command:

```
./runInstaller -record -destinationFile myresponsefile.rsp
```

The first one is my preferred because you can easily install and patch the database with the last PSU available, then you have a consolidated installation can be moved around. Of course all systems must be already prepared with needed packages.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this task as I had to provide some kind of simple "single click offline setup" for customers, intended to install Oracle11R2 DB on their (probably not connected to internet) Linux stations. The details of this "how to" is published at [my blog](http://www.oraclecommunity.net/profiles/blogs/how-to-make-automated-oracle-11gr2-installer-for-linux-centos-and). I will try to present here a brief summary:

Everyone, who tried to install Oracle DB on Linux – knows how many boring steps need to pass through. As result of my job I got a directory “orainst” with all need resources (files, scripts and directory with  optionally needed RPMs) inside. All you need is to save it on DVD (or ISO) and use it on your target station. Just enter into “orainst” and run “./setup.sh”

The our goal – to build installation package, included all needed files and directories which need to successful Oracle setup in Linux station, disconnected from internet. First of all, we already have a great helper for our job. As Oracle installation process became more and more complex Oracle decided to launch Oracle Preinstall RPM, with name of intended- to-install product contained into RPM’s name. In our case - oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall-1.0-6.el6.x86_64.rpm

The step-by-step instruction in blog describes in details how to prepare (optionally) the local yum repository for offline installation and how to fix Oracle Preinstall RPM if you don't want to deal with "kernel-uek", which is of course the Oracle Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel (also, optionally).

few words about installation script – “setup.sh”. It performs the following actions:

1. Checks if hostname exists into /etc/hosts and exits with error
   message if not. I noticed, that installation fails un case of
   hostname is not presented into /etc/hosts file.  May be, there is
   some other solution? I would like to get any other opinions
2. Configure yum local repository , which contained all needed packages
   to be installed by   oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall rpm as
   part of preinstallation tasks. It also will clean this configuration
   after preinstall ended. If you intend to use regular yum
   configuration (say web repository) and not need this local
   repository, you can remove all yum-related statements from script.
3. Run   oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall rpm, which do all
   difficult staff – configure OS kernel, install patches and packages
   and creates oracle user and group.
4. Run Oracle installer.  Oracle installer uses response file
   db-MYDB.rsp, which contained db installation parameters (in example
   supposed that SID chosen as “MYDB”).
5. Run postinstall scripts as root user.
6. Update /etc/oratab file and create “oracle” service for automated
   startup on boot (and with start/stop/monitor commands)

If someone tried to repeat my experience I would happy to get your comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage first the pre-installation tasks. Depending on the OS, a package is provided. 
If you are running Red Hat 7, look for the RSFO package in https://github.com/yannallandit/rsfo. It will complete all the pre-installation steps in up to 12 nodes in parallel.
A package allowing the database silent install also exists:
https://github.com/yannallandit/Install-Oracle